# Laptops Battery not holding much recently Acer Predator g3 571

Tags: windows, windows-10, battery, battery-life

my Acer Predator's battery isn't holding it anymore it used to do 2 to 3 hours on power-saving mode, not it only does an hour and a half, this starts to happen recently according to the battery report review (Enclosed a [screenshot of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaRVc.jpg)) so what seems to be the problem I checked the window update I'm on 1909 windows 10 latest version, Drivers all up to date, Using throttlestop for ultra battery consumption, what else can I do?

Comment: Lithium laptop batteries have a lifespan of between 300 - 500 discharge-charge cycles before they're unable to hold a full charge, so @RedGrittyBrick's answer would be recommended. It's recommended to: Configure the laptop to stop charging the battery at 80% if wanting more than the 300 - 500 charge-discharge cycles (increases it to ~800 - 1000 cycles - 3rd party software would likely be required); Use OEM, else 3rd party, software to limit charging if the laptop is continually plugged in; Disable any type of Rapid Charge. Physics: Li batteries degrade from higher & constant charge voltages.

Comment: Its likely a cell in the battery has gone faulty. This can cause the battery to drain other batteries, and on laptop batteries means replacing the battery pack.

Comment: Adding to @jw0914 comment - you should also not let your batteries discharge below about 15% as full discharge is very damaging - much more so then full charge.

Comment: I already solved the problem using throttlestop and hours of googling. I had a high power usage all the time and the reason was an NVidia Container service that was constantly using power constantly my power estimates increased from 1:30 mins till 3:20 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I fixed the problem after many scenarios, on throttlestop the power consumption was always over 14w so I tried disabling some of the startup services ( based on a recommendation) and the service responsible for the High power consumption was Nvidia Local System Container disabling it decreased the consumption to 2~4w and gave me a 100% battery boost from 1:30 to 3:10 (on 100% Full charge)

Answer (score 2):

> what else can I do?

Buy a new battery.

You don't say how old your battery is or what type it is but batteries don't last forever and their life can be shortened by certain usage patterns (depending on the type of battery chemistry)